# BST Insertion vs Deletion Python

Tags: binary-search-tree

When I try to insert a *sorted* list into a BST and try to delete that list from the BST, the insertion turns out to be a LOT slower than deletion.

However, if the list was unsorted (i.e. random), the time is about the same.

Could someone please explain why this might be? The language is in Python

Comment: You mean deleting is delete all or delete one by one?

Comment: Please provide the section of code that you are using to insert the list like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027841/python-create-a-binary-search-tree-using-a-list as well as the list size/quantity to get more clarity.

Comment: its delete one by one and the quantity is about 100000